# MySQL products storing - architecture

Tags: mysql, database-design, redis, mysql-5.7

I need to lay down architecture for app.  It's designed for selling products.

System is going to accept about 30-40k of new products daily.
It will lead to creation of new records in table **product**.

System should keep history of prices. User should be able to see how price of product A  got changed during last year.

So I have two options:

1. When a new product comes, I move (copy and remove) old products to another table. Let's name it  **product_history** .  So **product** table contains ONLY products which are being sold at the moment.  As result I will need to rewrite queries because row from product  can be either in table product or in table product_history  (If client wants to see history of sales, statistics, etc).
2. Nothing gets removed. I keep old products lying in the same table and just mark them as old with some attribute ("is_old").  The new records are indexed by Redis.

Solution 2 makes code easier but I  fear that table can large too grow.
 Advantages are that there no copying of data. No messing with removing.

Solution 1 makes  supporting  the system higher. Active table **product** will always stay small.  But playing always with two tables is harder than with one table.

One thing to note, not related to question, but it makes things a bit more complex: every product can have up to 12 different prices(probably more in the future). So the field price is stored as json and gets indexed by Redis already.

Which solution should bring less pain in the future? Which one would you pick?

Comment: yes, position is a product

Comment: I'd go for option 2 - but I'd probably store a date rather than an `is_old` flag. Then, an 'is_old' product is simply any product that doesn't have the latest date for that product. In 10 years, you will have ca. 150m entries, at which point you may want to get a bigger machine.

Answer (score 0):

My pick would be:
1. Go for option#2, it is cleaner, the migration part of option#1 adds to the write load & complexity.

2. Use an 'active' flag for each product item, which is 1 or true by default.
3. Partition the table on active flag, so that active items, which are the only queried items, lie in single partition, and inactive in other.
4. For pricing, do not store the json as a varchar/text, use a [native JSON field](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) ( mysql 5.7+), it would allow you richer querying within your JSON.
5. For redis sync, I would also suggest exploring [debezium](http://debezium.io/) to stream mysql changes to redis.